# How to make sure that the User is not able to take the Attendance of the same class on the same day?

Tags: java

I am working on a program, that allows the User to manage student information and also take attendance. Now in the method `take_attendance()` every student in a particular class is displayed and the user has to mark him absent, present or late. However, this method is not completely perfect as the User might mark the attendance of this class again on the same day. By convention attendance is a daily activity and I want to somehow block the user from marking the attendance for that particular day. Is there a way to do that?

PS: If my requirement is not clear then consider the following example. Suppose today on Jan 14 the User marks the attendance of a class "10 A." I want to write a program that will not let the user mark the attendance again until it is Jan 15 and so on. Any Insights will be highly appreciated. I have not posted the code for the `take_attendance()` method as it is quite cumbersome and frankly might not be helpful. But if you do require it, please tell me.

Thank You...

Comment: I think "conceptually" your idea might be wrong.  An attendance has some basic information, `Date`, `Student`, `Class`.  So with that information, it should be impossible to have more then one `Student` attend a `Class` on the `Date`, as a "record" would already exist. How you implement this would depend on how you data is been managed, but in SQL database environment, you should be able to set up a "unique" constraint on the three (or more) main fields

Comment: I am using File Handling in Java

Comment: Well, conceptually, it's still the same thing, you need to verify that no record exists in your file that would violate your rules.  When taking attendance, the user should be presented with "todays" current attendance (from the file), so they don't make any mistakes and/or know that an attendance has been done

Comment: So do you suggest that I am separated files for each date?

Comment: I'd recommend using a database of some kind.  How you manage your files is up to you, but you need to have some kind of "manager" which is responsible for managing the access to the "files" and managing the business logic associated with them. This is typically what people call a "data source"

Answer (score 1):

Create a compound key in the database consisting of the student's id, the class's id and the date / timeslot.

If there is a unique constraint on this key for this table, and the method is called twice by the same student for the same class, the database will throw an Exception.

Comment: *"I am using File Handling in Java"*

Comment: What is a compound key?

Comment: "Both composite key and compound key describe a candidate key with more than one attribute. According to the Relational Database Dictionary (C.J.Date) they mean the same thing." [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3137/46529)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to keep attendance records in a Set; this has the same effect as a constraint (because .equals() uses the three key fields which the constraint is based on - Date, studentId, classId).  Use the 'contains' method to validate duplicate entries.  It is important to note that Date must not contain the time.  The details follow:

```
public class Attendance {

private Date date;   // MUST NOT CONTAIN TIME!
private String studentId;
private String classId;
private String remark;  // Absent, present, late

public Attendance(Date date, String studentId, String classId, String remark) {
    super();
    this.date = date;
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.classId = classId;
    this.remark = remark;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}
public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}
public String getClassId() {
    return classId;
}
public void setClassId(String classId) {
    this.classId = classId;
}
public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}
public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((classId == null) ? 0 : classId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((studentId == null) ? 0 : studentId.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Attendance other = (Attendance) obj;
    if (classId == null) {
        if (other.classId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!classId.equals(other.classId))
        return false;
    if (date == null) {
        if (other.date != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
        return false;
    if (studentId == null) {
        if (other.studentId != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!studentId.equals(other.studentId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

Now here is how it works in principle. You build an Attendance record, and see if exists (Set.contains) in the set.  If it does, flag it.  If not, add.  If your records are all in a file, you need to read that file into the Set, but presumably you can manage the set in cache?

```
public class Tracker {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Set<Attendance> attendance = new HashSet<Attendance>();

Date jan14 = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToDate("2016-01-14"); // A helper class of mine to strip out any time value
String student1 = "S142";
String student2 = "S143";
String classId1 = "A10";
String classId2 = "A11";

Attendance a1 = new Attendance(jan14, student1, classId1, "Present");
Attendance a2 = new Attendance(jan14, student2, classId1, "Present");
Attendance a3 = new Attendance(jan14, student1, classId1, "Present");
Attendance a4 = new Attendance(jan14, student2, classId1, "Present");

attendance.add(a1);   // Add record to seed the Set
attendance.add(a2);   // Add another

System.out.println(attendance.contains(a3)); // True!

}
```